# Add a field to Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a field called jobsPosted as seen in the picture, so I want to add another job, I have dishwasher and waiter already. But I get an error with this query

```
     db.collection("companies").doc("Tiradito").field("jobsPosted").set(postJobObject).then(function() {
        console.log("Document successfully written!");
       });
```

That's my postJobbject

```
var postJobObject = {
      "position": this.state.selected,
      "timeSchedule": this.state.timeSchedule,
      "compensation" : this.state.compensation,
      "experience" : this.state.experience,
      "description" : this.state.description
    }
```

[image: Here is a link to an image of my firestore]

Comment: db.collection("companies").doc("Tiradito").field is not a function

Answer (score 15):

pass the option to merge the new data with any existing document to avoid overwriting entire documents

```
var cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('BJ');

var setWithMerge = cityRef.set({
    capital: true
}, { merge: true });
```

source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
    jobsPosted = {}

    var postJobObject = {
          "position": this.state.selected,
          "timeSchedule": this.state.timeSchedule,
          "compensation" : this.state.compensation,
          "experience" : this.state.experience,
          "description" : this.state.description
        }

jobsPosted['newJob'] = postJobObject;
```

Then use `update`

```
db.collection("companies").doc("Tiradito").update(jobsPosted).then(function() {
        console.log("Document successfully written!");
       });
```